# npm SSL errors: integrity checksum failed when using sha512

Tags: node.js, ssl, networking, npm

I cannot install anything with npm!

**What am I using?**

- node v10.16.0
- npm v6.9.0
- windows 7 x64
- **Corporate proxy with MITM content inspection tool** (Likely culprit)

**What am i doing?**

`npm install node-sass -g`

**What is happening?**

Depending on configuration, I encounter one of the two following errors:

```
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
```

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-3g8lYefrRRzvGeSowdJKAKyks8oUpLEd/DyPV4eMhVlhJ0aNaZqIrNUIPuEWWTAoPqyFkfGrM67MC69baqn6vA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-3g8lYefrRRzvGeSowdJKAKyks8oUpLEd/DyPV4eMhVlhJ0aNaZqIrNUIPuEWWTAoPqyFkfGrM67MC69baqn6vA== but got sha512-jIvvQweolCmipqZXjsC8NUIKS/iux7/bKsBBZQCCMibvCg/eNyz0L7L7ddO9r1dRStqWyBlrHFUPRrF56wCr/A==. (2121 bytes)
```

**What have I tried?**

**Proxy configuration:**

`npm config set http-proxy http://user:password@proxy:port`

`npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy:port`

*This alone used to work.*

**Clean install:**

I have uninstalled Node and npm, deleted the folders `npm` and `npm-cache` from `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming` and deleted `.npmrc` from `C:\Users\me`. 
I have also ran `npm cache clean --force` & `npm cache verify`

Following this I have tried a fresh install of Node v10.16.0 & v10.15.3 (npm 6.4.1)

**Disable SSL:**

- `npm config set strict-ssl false`
- set windows local and system evnironment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to 0

**CA configuration:**

I have exported all my corporate certificates from `Internet Options > content > certificates > trusted root certification authorities`. I have exported them to individual Base 64 encoded X.509 `.cer` files and created a separate `bundle.cer` file and merged them all together.

I have then tried using this in all of the following ways:

- `npm config set cafile C:\\certs\\cert1.cer`
- `npm config set cafile C:\\certs\\cert2.cer`
- `npm config set cafile C:\\certs\\cert3.cer`
- `npm config set cafile C:\\certs\\bundle.cer`
- `npm config set ca BASE64-code-taken-from-each-cer-file`
- set windows environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` to each file above.

**Package-lock:**

Some posts suggest deleting a `package-lock.json`. I do not have this as I am installing globally and not in a local project. I have tried installing without the global flag in a local directory. I get the same SSL issues.

Help!

Comment: Short term solution: IT added an exemption for npm registry. Would still like to know how to correctly configure npm to work behind proxy and MITM.

Comment: did u found answer?

Comment: @AndiAR Other than white-listing, unfortunately not.